# how to get data from backend in nuxt 3 without using composition api

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I hope you are fine. I want to send a get request in nuxt3 without using composition api but I don't know how to do that. I will thank anyone who give me a piece of guidance.
Thanks.

```
async getPosters(){
        const results = await this.$axios.get('posters')
        this.posters = results.data
    },
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Also, please explain why you can't use the composition API?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Soviut; The reason is that because I don't have any knowledge about composition api so I prefer to use option api. Is it possible to help me to solve this please?

Comment: Also, please give a read to that one: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/data-fetching/#options-api-support

Answer (score 0):

Write your code as you were used too with just Options API, nothing have changed on that matter.
You can totally use Options API while using Vue3/Nuxt3. They may have some small changes but nothing too major for a simple task of querying a backend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @kissu .The problem is that while I was using vue option api I was working with axios but in nuxt3 it is not possible to use axios and this is the reason that I want to know what is the code of sending a get request to backend in nuxt3 without using composition api. Is it possible to help me to solve this please?

Comment: @MohammadGhiasvand how is it not possible to use Axios? Import it and call it as usual. Otherwise, if you want to use the module, you still should have access to `this.$axios`. Again, some code on your side would be quite welcome as mentioned in an upper comment.

Comment: OK @kissu, I have put a piece of my code in my question and this code is not working.

Comment: Is it possible to tell me how to install axios for nuxt , please? @kissu

Comment: @MohammadGhiasvand as for Nuxt2: check the documentation for the modules on Github for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is more of an issue with trying to load Axios rather than it is with the composition API. Nuxt 3 makes Axios a redundant module.

Since Fetch is the go-to considered method of requesting data in Nuxt3, have you tried changing the method of your request? It means having to load one less module for your project, and will make it a lot easier to transition between SSR and Static in the future. If not, it might be worth using the previous version of Nuxt.

Here's the documentation: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/data-fetching in Nuxt 3.